# HTML injection: cannot insert javascript into textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-injections

I'm testing a page I made in PHP for HTML injections, but it's not working the way I expected.

I'm trying to insert

```
<div onmouseover="alert(1)" style="position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:9999px;height:9999px;">
</div>
```

inside a textarea. Server-side, I just want to display $_GET with a var_dump for now but it doesn't even get to that: when I click the button it just brings me back to the homepage and `#3377832596384266514` is added to the URL. I don't get any error in PHP so maybe it's a server issue (Apache 2.4).

I'm guessing some part of the stack is being defensive, like when you add `javascript:` to a URL and the browser gets rid of it, but I don't know where to look. I've also tried

```
<script>alert(foo);</script>
```

and other variations but then the `<` and some other characters are stripped.

```
test.php
<!doctype html>
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="select.php">
        <p>
            <label for="select">Words
                <textarea id="select"
                       name="select"
                       cols="50"
                       rows="1"
                       maxlength="100"
                       required
                       autofocus></textarea>
            </label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button>Send</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


select.php
<?php
    var_dump($_GET);
```

Edit: textarea instead of input.

Edit: added all the code.

Comment: Sometimes your server does that.  So it's intercepted and stripped even before your PHP sees it, let alone the broswer.

Comment: You need to show your PHP code if we're to have any chance of figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: @durbnpoisn yeah that would explain it but is it standard? Is it caused by a config file?

Comment: Need more code to work with. Show your form, (the) button, and any other relevant information/code. Not pseudo code like `<script>alert(foo);</script>`, unless you've actually declared `foo` somewhere. Let's see the `<textarea>...</textarea>` and all.

Comment: @Marcus I added the code. However what I tried to input into the textarea _was_ pseudo code... Specifically any HTML special character.

Comment: I guess the most overlooked part of this is why `#3377832596384266514` is being added to the URL. Are you sure you're including *everything*? What's your `.htaccess` file look like? You have one?

Comment: If you change your form method to `POST`, do you still encounter the same issue? Really though. Your code is as basic as it comes. This should not be tripping up your server (as you thought it might). There's gotta be more to this.

Comment: @Marcus you were right! I changed `GET` to `POST` and it works fine...

Comment: Weird. I had a feeling that might be the case. Thinking the URL-string, being filled full of HTML from your injection test, might have been triggering something in your server settings that you were unaware of, ie. a mod_rewrite of sorts causing an automagic redirect back to the homepage with that number appended to the URL. I added it as an answer below for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the form method from `GET` to `POST`.

`GET` is possibly causing an issue with how the server handles certain *markup* in the URL.

OP verified this resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Input tags can't have any content, that's why you can set it as an self-closing element `<input />`

maybe you need another approach

Comment: My mistake, actually I'm using a textarea!

Comment: `textarea` can only contain plain text.